# ¿Cual es el mejor método para imprimir a pantalla? ¿Con String o con void?

Tags: java

Tengo una duda con un código. Es mejor usar un método:

```
public void dameNombre(){
System.out.printl(this.nombre);
}
```

o es mejor usar

```
public String dameNombre(){
return this.nombre;
}
```

La diferencia es que en el ***main***
se mandan a llamar de diferente manera:

```
ejemplo.dameNombre();
```

y el otro es por medio del:

```
System.out.println(ejemplo.dameNombre());
```

¿Cual consideran que es la mejor manera? Soy novato, y me surgen estas dudas.
¿Cómo sé cual utilizar? ¿Cual es la diferencia una de otra?

Comment: Quieres mostrar simplemente el valor a pantalla?

Comment: sí, solo quiero mostrar el valor.

Comment: No entiendo que esta pregunta no se haya cerrado. Es una pregunta que depende claramente de una opinión o de cómo alguien prefiere hacer "algo". No hay ningún problema de programación explicito ni implicito que haya que solucionar o explicar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta tu comentario, deberías usar la primera función, pero yo le cambiaría el nombre, debemos poner nombres entendibles a nuestras funciones, así nos será más fácil localizar su utilidad, en este caso sería así:

```
public void mostrarNombre(){//public void dameNombre() canviamos nombre de la función
System.out.printl(this.nombre);
}
```

De esta manera en el ***main*** sólo deberás llamar la función sin esperar devolver una variable, la llamada será más sencilla:

```
ejemplo.mostrarNombre();
```

En este caso, repito, EN ESTE CASO sería mejor usar esta opción. Si fuese cualquier otra manera, usaría la segunda opción ya que devolvemos un valor y con ese valor podemos hacer cualquier cosa... (guardar-lo,modificar-lo,tratar-lo...)

Espero haver sido de ayuda.

[java](/questions/tagged/java)

Answer (score 3):

Lo mejor es devolver el valor como un `String` (o el tipo de dato correspondiente) y que el cliente de esta clase, en este caso tu clase principal, se encargue de usar el dato para alguna tarea. En este caso, la tarea es imprimir el nombre en el terminal, en otros casos puede ser imprimir el nombre en una página web, en otros puede ser un parámetro para un query, etc.